# Laravel 5 mod_rewrite not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And then in my Laravel public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

URL:
http://sub.domain.se/user/login
does not work.

But
http://sub.domain.se/index.php/user/login

works.

When writing: apachectl -M

rewrite_module (shared) is included

In sites-enabled:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sub.domain.se
        DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Already restart your apache sever?

Comment: Yep, I've tried restart the Apache server a couple of times already.

Answer (score 0):

My working `.htaccess` file is following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        #Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```